# What is the best location to store binary overlays that are applied at runtime?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree, overlayfs

Binary overlays that are applied while booting would probably best be stored in `/boot/overlays` or similar. However, what is the best location for binary device-tree overlay files that are intended to be used at runtime?
Two candidate locations that come to mind are `/etc` and `/lib`:

- `/etc` contains configuration files and overlays are somehow similar to configuration files. That being said, they are binary and not intended for editing
- `/lib` contains binary files, but usually these contain executable code. Doesn't seem to be the right spot either

Neither really fits well. Is there a preferred location that I overlooked?

Comment: maybe /usr/bin?

Comment: I have also thought about `/usr/bin` or just `bin` but that seems sub-optimal as well as `bin` is usually meant for executables, right?